# How to handle image with dynamically using react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

> Here is my scenario  Using  component i am displaying the
>   images.

```
var ImageRender = React.createClass({
    render : function(){
       return (<View style={{marginLeft:15,marginRight:15}}>
                   <Image source={uri} style={{height:220}}/>
               </View>)
    }
});
```

> here if i specify width for image  then  i opened this component in
>   another type of resolution that image width is not suitable.how to
>   achieve this image widt dynamically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first get the device dimensions...

```
var Dimensions = require('Dimensions');
var {
  width,
  height
} = Dimensions.get('window');
```

then use them...

```
var ImageRender = React.createClass({ render : function(){ return (<View style={{marginLeft:15,marginRight:15}}> <Image source={uri} style={{height:220, width:width}}/> </View>) } });
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.It's worked but i am getting one error i.e JSON value '{width=375} of type NSDictionary cannot be converted to NSNumber.How to convert json object to number using react native

Comment: maybe I didn't need to wrap the value in its own curly brackets. try without